# Como obtener los elementos de un Datacontainer con Python y selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Hola amigos buenos días.

Me encuentro haicendo un programa para extracción de información de varias paginas de internet con python y Selenium, y debo obtener un archivo de excel de la siguiente ruta:

https://sinergox.xm.com.co/dmnd/Paginas/Historicos/Historicos.aspx

Necesito descargar el ultimo arhchivo de los llamado **"Demanda_comercial_no_regulada_por_ciiu..."** y veo que esta la opcion de ordenar por fecha, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al inspeccionar la pagina veo que es una clase de tipo xm_dataContainer, sin embargo no tengo conocimiento de como ordenear y obtener el elemento mas reciente.

Agradezco de alguien que me pueda brindar una ayuda y una idea de como hacerlo.  Muchas gracias

Comment: Tengo la respuesta a la primera pregunta (como ordenar por fecha de modificación) pero te la mostraré si nos muestras lo que has intentado para resolver tu propia duda. De ese modo, sabremos que no te hacemos la tarea.

Comment: Hola @DanteS.  entiendo lo que me dices.  Para serte sincero si vine a buscar una respuesta ya que he pensando que debo iterar entre los elementos que estan en ese contenedor y obtener el nombre del elemento y la fecha.  Sin embargo no se como hacerlo ya que no soy tan experto en estos temas.  Igual agradezco enormemente tu respuesta.  Saludos.